# Listing directory in MATLAB does not work with fish

Tags: matlab, shell, fish

After I setup `fish` as the main shell `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish`, I've tried to use `ls` command in MATLAB, but I got the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> ls at 36
/usr/local/bin/fish: /opt/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
not found (required by /usr/local/bin/fish)
```

Someone knows why it happens? My actual solution is to reset `bash` as the main shell and always run `fish` to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab uses its own glibc librarires, and it's often a big mess because of that.

You can look at my answer there for one way to solve that:
[GLIBCXX not found when compiling vtk example under mex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421708/glibcxx-not-found-when-compiling-vtk-example-under-mex/8422003#8422003)

Comment: Thanks, your solution has worked. But now I have a problem with Matlab color control sequences, like http://www.mail-archive.com/fish-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00452.html